# Serial Link Between 3.3V devices

Tags: serial, raspberry-pi, rs232, python, freescale

I have an RPi and a freescale FRDM-KL25z controller which will talk over serial protocol. I'm using the pyserial library on the pi:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
ser.write('hi FRDM')
```

and using the serial protocol from the mbed library will generate interrupts to process the data from the Pi.

https://developer.mbed.org/users/mbed_official/code/mbed/docs/4fc01daae5a5/classmbed_1_1SerialBase.html#ae67fb9b5a2ee2f4e98a39cdab10ed090

My question is, having two devices which talk over the same protocol at the same potential and in close proximity, do I need a logic level converter or some form of UART chip?

I would think not, but I am aware that RS232 is a +-12V protocol so would just like to ensure that this assumption is correct.

Comment: If you're using /dev/ttyACM0 then you're using CDC/ACM not RS232.

Comment: does that mean this code uses one of the USB ports? I plan to use the GPIO pins 8 and 10.

Comment: Yes, that code is using USB.  For the hardware UART you would use /dev/ttyAMA0 instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both share the same logic levels (0V-3.3V) and the same ground it shouldn't be a problem. But then you aren't using RS232, just UART. The Serial bridge on the Arduinos works the same way. The FTDI chip uses 0V-5V and the ATmega uses 0V-5V.

Comment: You hit the problem on the head. If one device is using CMOS logic levels (3.3V), and the other is using TTL logic levels (5V), the logic thresholds are different. A logic high is > ~60% of the working voltage (2V for 3.3V logic and 3V for 5V logic). To operate properly he needs a level shifter on either side such as a MAX3232, or a buffer that is tolerant of either logic family.

Comment: @cowboydan Are you referring to me by 'he'? Both devices are 3.3V so as I believe David has said I don't think I need any level shifting..

Comment: @cowboydan, in a word, NO!  A charge pump device like a max3232 is an *absurd* suggestion for 3.3-5v translation.  And don't make assumptions of threshold voltage without checking data sheets - some 5v devices have a *lower* VIH than some 3.3v devices.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - quite right. After re-reading my comment the MAX3232 doesn't seem to make sense here.